# How do purely functional compilers annotate the AST with type info?

Tags: scala, haskell, compiler-construction, f#, functional-programming

In the syntax analysis phase, an imperative compiler can build an AST out of nodes that already contain a `type` field that is set to `null` during construction, and then later, in the semantic analysis phase, fill in the types by assigning the declared/inferred types into the `type` fields.

How do purely functional languages handle this, where you do not have the luxury of assignment? Is the type-less AST mapped to a different *kind* of type-enriched AST? Does that mean I need to define two types per AST node, one for the syntax phase, and one for the semantic phase?

Are there purely functional programming tricks that help the compiler writer with this problem?

Comment: How does lacking assignment cause a problem, exactly? I'm not sure I follow...

Comment: The fact that it's an AST is nothing special; this "problem" is no different to any other situation where an imperative programmer would use mutation to update a structure.

Comment: @Ben Right, but the interesting twist is it's a recursive structure based on nodes.

Comment: The new C# and VB.NET compilers by Microsoft (codename Roslyn) are purely functional and open-source, in addition to being industrial-strength production-ready "real-world" compilers. They are also compilers for an imperative language written in an imperative language in a purely functional style. (Well, at least the data structures are immutable.)

Comment: @fredoverflow Yes, but I'm afraid that's not actually a twist. Recursive data structures are *incredibly* common in in functional programming, and the need to "update" them is a problem functional programmers encounter very early in their learning, in almost any domain (not just compilers). So to a certain extent, this question is yet another iteration of "how does pure functional programming work without mutation?".

Comment: @Ben Yes, adding a number to a tree of numbers is very common and well-understood. But how common is it that you need to add another field to the element type of the tree later? I'd imagine there are lots of possible solutions to this problem, but I have no practical experience.

Comment: @JörgWMittag It would be awesome if you could finde the time to condense Roslyn's approach into an answer :)

Comment: @fredoverflow Ah, I misunderstood then! But in that case you're making a false comparison between imperative and functional; you can only assign the `type` field to `null` in the imperative compiler because you already prepared for the need to later add type annotation, and included a `type` field in your ADT to initially be `null`. You can do *exactly* the same thing in a pure functional approach, by adding a type field that can be set to a value that indicates "not yet tagged with a type" (probably `Maybe TypeInfo` initially set to `Nothing`, in Haskellish terms).

Comment: @fredoverflow There are also lots of other ways (external tags, using generics to support an arbitrary "extra" field in your records). But those also have very little to do with imperative vs functional programming, and could be just as well used by an imperative compiler.

Comment: @Ben Sure, but the "functional null" approach seems super hacky to me. At least way more hacky than the "imperative null" approach :)

Comment: @fredoverflow Really? I find nulls *way* more hacky than than maybes! And imperative-ness has nothing to do with it. Anyway, I've diverged quite a way from commenting on the original question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like in the case when dealing with relational databases, in functional programming it is often a good idea not to put everything in a single data structure.

In particular, there may not be a data structure that is "the AST".

Most probably, there will be data structures that represent parsed expressions. One possible way to deal with type information is to assign a unique identifier (like an integer) to each node of the tree already during parsing and have some suitable data structure (like a hash map) that associates those node-ids with types. The job of the type inference pass, then, would be just to create this map.

Answer (score 6):

I usually rewrite a source (or an already several steps lowered) AST into a new form, replacing each `expression` node with a pair `(tag, expression)`.

Tags are unique numbers or symbols which are then used by the next pass which derives type equations from the AST. E.g., `a + b` will yield something like { `numeric(Tag_a).` `numeric(Tag_b).` `equals(Tag_a, Tag_b).` `equals(Tag_e, Tag_a).`}.

Then types equations are solved (e.g., by simply running them as a Prolog program), and, if successful, all the tags (which are variables in this program) are now bound to concrete types, and if not, they're left as type parameters.

In a next step, our previous AST is rewritten again, this time replacing tags with all the inferred type information.

The whole process is a sequence of pure rewrites, no need to replace anything in your AST destructively. A typical compilation pipeline may take a couple of dozens of rewrites, some of them changing the AST datatype.

Answer (score 3):

There are several options to model this. You may use the same kind of nullable data fields as in your imperative case:

```hs
data Exp = Var Name (Maybe Type) | ...
parse :: String -> Maybe Exp     -- types are Nothings here
typeCheck :: Exp -> Maybe Exp    -- turns Nothings into Justs
```

or even, using a more precise type

```hs
data Exp ty = Var Name ty | ...
parse :: String -> Maybe (Exp ())
typeCheck :: Exp () -> Maybe (Exp Type)
```

Answer (score 3):

I cant speak for how it is *supposed* to be done, but I did do this in F# for a C# compiler [here](https://github.com/neildanson/MicroCS)

The approach was basically - build an AST from the source, leaving things like type information unconstrained - So AST.fs basically is the AST which strings for the type names, function names, etc.

As the AST starts to be compiled to (in this case) .NET IL, we end up with more type information (we create the types in the source - lets call these type-stubs). This then gives us the information needed to created method-stubs (the code may have signatures that include type-stubs as well as built in types). From here we now have enough type information to resolve any of the type names, or method signatures in the code.

I store that in the file TypedAST.fs. I do this in a single pass, however the approach may be naive.

Now we have a fully typed AST you could then do things like compile it, fully analyze it, or whatever you like with it.

So in answer to the question "*Does that mean I need to define two types per AST node, one for the syntax phase, and one for the semantic phase?*", I cant say definitively that this is the case, but it is certainly what I did, and it appears to be what MS have done with Roslyn (although they have essentially decorated the original tree with type info IIRC)

"*Are there purely functional programming tricks that help the compiler writer with this problem?*"
Given the ASTs are essentially mirrored in my case, it would be possible to make it generic and transform the tree, but the code *may* end up (more) horrendous.

i.e.

```
type 'type AST;
| MethodInvoke of 'type * Name * 'type list
| ....
```